# Why doesn't likely and unlikely macros have any effect on ARM assembly code?

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, arm, likely-unlikely

I took below example from https://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/LikelyUnlikely

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define likely(x)    __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)  __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)

int main(char *argv[], int argc)
{
   int a;

   /* Get the value from somewhere GCC can't optimize */
   a = atoi (argv[1]);

   if (likely (a == 2))
      a++;
   else
      a--;

   printf ("%d\n", a);

   return 0;
}
```

and compiled it https://godbolt.org/z/IC0aif with `arm gcc 8.2 compiler`.

In the original link, they have tested it for X86 and the assembly output is different if `likely`(in the if condition in above code) is replaced with `unlikely`, which shows the optimisation performed by compiler for branch prediction.

But when I compile the above code for ARM (arm-gcc -O2), I don't see any difference in assembly code. Below is the output of ARM assembly in both the case - `likely` and `unlikely`

```
main:
        push    {r4, lr}
        ldr     r0, [r0, #4]
        bl      atoi
        cmp     r0, #2
        subne   r1, r0, #1
        moveq   r1, #3
        ldr     r0, .L6
        bl      printf
        mov     r0, #0
        pop     {r4, pc}
.L6:
        .word   .LC0
.LC0:
        .ascii  "%d\012\000"
```

Why doesn't the compiler optimize for branch prediction in case of ARM ?

Comment: This could depend on the exact ARM CPU targeted, as some have shallow pipelines and no branch-prediction units.

Comment: There is no branch prediction because there is no branch. ARM lets you put a condition on most instructions. For example, `subne` does the subtraction only if the last comparison was "not equal" while `moveq` only moves the literal value if the last comparison was "equal".

Comment: @rici - so likely/unlikely is not so useful in case of ARM ?

Comment: I didn't say that. Here, the conditional actions are very simple. For more complicated conditionals, branching will be required and likely/unlikely will probably affect code generation. How much difference that actually makes (on any platform) is another question.

Comment: @rici - Thanks. Got it.

Comment: 1) there is no reason to assume that this will improve the code output for any target.  2) there is no reason to assume that a compiler cant figure this out.

Comment: This is to some extent ghee whiz trying to mess with the language.  And also falls into premature optimization.  Also with something like gcc or clang it has a time limit, might work on the day on the machine on that compiler and version for that target that it was written.  But over time if not already in a version not yet on that computer that day, the compiler can figure this out with improvements or sometimes accidents.  Likewise improvements or accidents can cause this optimization to fail.

Comment: It doesnt hurt to re-organize the if and else to improve a warm fuzzy feeling inside the programmer, but no reason to assume it will make a difference and more important no reason to expect it will always make a difference for any platform much less a specific one.

Comment: Why downvote the question? The question is genuine and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rici said, your code is simple enough that it can be realized by conditional instructions. You can see a difference, e.g., if you call functions which are implemented in a different compilation unit:

```
#define likely(x)    __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)  __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)

// only forward declarations:
void foo();
void bar();

int main(char *argv[], int argc)
{
   if (likely (argc == 2))
      foo();
   else
      bar();
}
```

Changing `likely` to `unlikely` switches the order of the `if` and `else` branch, for ARM and x86: https://godbolt.org/z/UDzvf0. If this really makes a difference likely depends on the hardware you are running on, whether you call the function the first time (otherwise, the CPU-internal branch prediction likely has a higher influence than the order of the instructions), and probably many other things.